# Add attic access in garage?

Tags: attic

I'm going to need access to the attic area of my house to run some cables. The current access is in a closet on the opposite end of the house; getting up there is a bit of a pain, and then I would have to traverse the length of the house by hopping from truss to truss. I'm thinking about adding an attic access in the garage to make things easier. Is there any reason (building code, security, ???) not to add an attic access in the garage?

Comment: Unless you spend a lot of time going in and out of your attic, (as in, before and after this one project) I'd not bother with the major surgery of a new access hole, but I would consider passing some planks or plywood up to make a path from truss to truss, rather than "hopping."

Comment: Make sure the access can be sealed to block out exhaust fume..

Comment: If I were you (and I probably will be doing this exact thing sometime in the next year), I wouldn't bother with a permanent attic access in the garage.  Rather, I'd just take down that piece of drywall, and put up a new piece when I'm done, which will be much cheaper, and easy to make code-compliant.  Though in my case, I'm planning to bury the whole thing in cellulose after I'm done cabling, so access to the attic after that will be a ton of work no matter how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Ecnerwal's comment, I added some planks between the rafters, and now find it much easier to traverse the attic. No need for a new access hole.

Answer (score 4):

If you cut an access hole from the garage to the house attic, remember there must be 1/2” gypsum board on the garage side of the access hatch to meet code.

If you put a small door in the wall, make sure it’s at least 1 3/8” thick, solid core and latches to meet code.